# Auto Scale text to fit the screen in mono

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

I'm trying to scale a given text, e.g "123\nV.1-4", to fit the screen in mono.
I tried increasing the font size till the screen is not bigger.

My main problem is that I cannot retrieve the size of the label with a new font quickly?
(I'm retrieving with `label.GetSizeRequest(out width, out height);`)

So any solutions on how to scale the font/text?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When the label is resized as you change the font size, the SizeRequest and SizeAllocated events will fire. What you could do is set the font size, then in the SizeAllocated event for the label, set the font size again. You will clearly have to stop the loop at some point, I assume you would cease increasing the font size when your label dimensions outstrip those of the window or screen etc.

However, have you considering using Pango and a drawing area instead?